# Make a repository call using JPA where table name is a keyword in SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I am trying to write a Repository call in my microservices using JPA, now the problem is that the table name for which I am trying to make a repository call is a reserved keyword in SQL i.e. 'CASE'

Currently to overcome this problem we are writing a native query like this in our Repository

```
@Repository
public interface CaseRepository extends JpaRepository<Case, Long> {
    @Query(value = "Select * from cft.\"case\" where id = :idCase", nativeQuery = true)
    Case findCaseById(Long idCase);
}
```

Since this is not a good approach so I am trying to remove nativeQuery and trying to do something like this

```
@Repository
public interface CaseRepository extends JpaRepository<Case, Long> {
      @Query("select c from Case c where c.id = :idCase")
      Cases getCaseById(Long idCase);
}
```

But this block of code is giving an error because Case is a reserved keyword. For this I tried to look for issues similar to this here in stackoverflow but the suggestion which I saw was that the name of Table needs to be changed but since in our case this table is being used in lot of places so can't take risk of changing the name.

Any hints regarding how we can overcome this issue are appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use double quotes in the name of the table so it takes the name literally. In your entity class you should use something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"case\"")
public class Case {
}
```

Comment: No this does not work. When we do this and specify the name literally, it then says that the Table not found 'case' and throws SchemaManagementException